# Why is this process a semimartingale? How is Itô's formula applied here?

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, martingales

I am reading chapter 24 of Kallenberg's modern probability. In the proof of theorem 24.1

> **Cauchy Problem:** $CP(f,v):\dot{u}=Au-vu$ and $u(0,x)=f(x)$.
>
> **Theorem 24.1.** (Cauchy problem, Feynman, Kac) Let $A$ with domain $D$ be the generator of a Feller diffusion $X$ in $\mathbb{R}^d$, and fix $u\in C_b(\mathbb{R}^d)$ and $v\in C_b^+(\mathbb{R}^d)$. Then any bounded solution $u:[0;\infty)\times\mathbb{R}^d\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ to $CP(f,v)$, that is $C^1$ in the time-variable and $C^2$ in the space variable, is given by
> $$
> u(t,x)=\mathbb{E}_x[e^{-V_t}f(X_t)],
> $$
> where $V_t=\int_0^t v(X_s)ds$.
> Conversely the function $u$ above solves $CP(f,v)$ if $f\in D$.

they define $M_s=e^{-V_s}u(t-s,X_s)$ for fixed $t$ and $s\in[0;t]$ and show that it is a local martingale. However they use Îto's formula, i.e. they try to express
$du(t-s,X_s)$ in terms of a second order expansion. But I don't understand why we are allowed to use Îto's formula, since we didn't show that $X_s$ is a semimartingale. So why is $X_s$ is a semimartingale?

They mention Dynkin's formula, Lemma 19.21,

> **Lemma 19.21** (Dynkin's formula). The processes $M^h_t=h(X_t)-h(X_0)-\int_0^t Ah(X_s)ds$ for $h\in D$ are martingales.

so do they say that by choosing a suitable $h$ we can see that $X_t$ is a semimartingale? We know that $C_c^\infty(\mathbb{R}^d)\subseteq D$ by definition of Feller diffusion. So we can try to plug in some $h$ that look close to $X_t$ like the identity and elsewhere are $0$. Since $A$ is local, $Ah$ will vanish there, so $M^h_t$ will look like $X_t$.

**Edit:** I also have difficulties in the proof of the above theorem to understand how Itôs formula is applied. They write
$$
dM_s = e^{-V_s}(du(t-s,X_s)-u(t-s,X_s)v(X_s)ds)
$$
by integration by parts. But then they mention Dynkin's formula and Itô's formula to write further
$$
dM_s = e^{-V_s}(Au(t-s,X_s)-\dot{u}(t-s,X_s)-u(t-s,X_s)v(X_s))ds + L_s,
$$
where $L_s$ is some local martingale. I don't understand at all, how $A$ comes into play when using Itô's formula on $u(t-s,X_s)$. When applying Itô's formula, we get in Einstein summation
$$
du(t-s,X_s)=\partial_ju(t-s,X_s)dX_s^j + \partial_i\partial_ju(t-s,X_s)d[X^i,X^j]_s.
$$
The local martingale part from the $dX_s^j$-integration can be absorbed into $L_s$, but how to relate all the other terms to $A$? What is $[X^i,X^j]$ in this case? I know that there is a formula relating a second order expansion with the generator of a Feller diffusion, Theorem 19.24 in Kallenberg, but nothing is said about uniqueness.

Answer (score 2):

You're on the right track. For each $x\in\Bbb R^d$ and $r>0$ let $f$ be a smooth continuous function of compact support such that $f(y) = y$ for all $y\in B(x,r)$. Then $f$ is in $D$ and so $f(X)$ is a semimartingale under $\Bbb P_x$. Therefore $X$ is a semimartingale up until the exit time $\inf\{t: X_t\notin B(x,r)\}$.  As $r$ can be made as large as you please, this shows that $X$ is a local semimartingale, hence a semimartingale under $\Bbb P_x$.

Comment: I just realised that $f$ as defined is a function from $\mathbb{R}^d$ to $\mathbb{R}^d$, but in $D\subseteq \{\text{functions from  } \mathbb{R}^d \text{  to  } \mathbb{R}\}$, i.e. our function needs to have values in $\mathbb{R}$. So how to fix this?

Comment: I guess instead of looking at the identity we can look at the $i$th coordinate projections and deduce that in every coordinate it is a semimartingale. Are there any complications perhaps?

Comment: I fail to see, how you deduce that $f(X)$ is a semimartingale, even if $f$ is the $i$th coordinate projection, since $Af\neq0$? I mean $f$ doesn't vanish on $B(x,r)$, it's somehow the opposite, so we cannot use that $A$ is local. Could you elaborate, why $f(X)$ should be a semimartingale? I am trying to use the formula for $A$ from Theorem 19.24, but unfortunately there are still integrals that don't vanish. Ah ok, I think I got an idea, i.e. I forgot to apply that semimartingales, are only semimartingales, i.e. the integrals are probably of finite variation.

Comment: That $f$ is in $D$ shows  that
$$
X_t=X_0+M_t+\int_0^t Af(X_s)\,ds,\qquad 0\le t<\tau(x,t),
$$
where $M$ is a martingale and $\tau(x,r)$ is the exit time of $X$ from the ball $B(x,r)$. This exhibits the semimartingale decomposition of the ($\Bbb R^d$-valued) process $X$ up to time $\tau(x,r)$.

Comment: No, I claim that $f$ is not in $D$, because $f$ takes values in $\mathbb{R}^d$ and not in $\mathbb{R}$. I have a follow up question, written in the edit, would help me a lot if you could answer it!

Comment: My bad.  Apply my suggestion to the $i$th coordinate of $f$.